# java.io.IOException: bt socket connect failed

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

Im using a bluetooth printer which i connect to my device using BlueToothSocket, etc. I've been successful with most of the devices but as of this week I have a new device which i just cant get the printer to connect to (open the socket that is, since it's successfully paired). I've used this two methods (used first one with both secure and insecure way):

```
mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```

AND

```
m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Followed by mmSocket.connect();

The problem is, that neither are working and the error shown is the one stated at the question: java.io.IOException: bt socket connect failed

What'd be causing this? I've tried this on a HTC ONE, a Sony Xperia, a Galaxy Tablet, Motorola phone etc.. But now im using this ACUBE 7 Phablet and it's not working. I have a feeling it's got to be something on the device build that's causing it to fail but cant figure out which way to work something out. Any ideas? Are there any other methods used to initiate a Bluetooth connection programmatically between paired devices?

Comment: Did you found a solution?